# How to set logs for API proxy in apigee

Tags: logging, request, response, apigee

How to setup logs in Apigee for set api proxy endpoint. I have set up a API proxy and need to track the proxy `request` and `response`. I have enabled the logs in the service in backend, I have to track the proxy calls and check the headers and body.

I have tracked the response through postman for the request, i guess something is missing.